# Xamarin binding library error "does not implement inherited abstract member" even when it was implemented

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, implementation

I'm binding a Xamarin library from Java. But I get this problem when I build it.

> Error 42  'Com.Almeros.Android.Multitouch.RotateGestureDetector' does
>   not implement inherited abstract member
>   'Com.Almeros.Android.Multitouch.BaseGestureDetector.HandleInProgressEvent(int,
>   Android.Views.MotionEvent)'

Even when I have this function

```
static IntPtr id_handleInProgressEvent_ILandroid_view_MotionEvent_;
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.almeros.android.multitouch']/class[@name='RotateGestureDetector']/method[@name='handleInProgressEvent' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='int'] and parameter[2][@type='android.view.MotionEvent']]"
        [Register ("handleInProgressEvent", "(ILandroid/view/MotionEvent;)V", "GetHandleInProgressEvent_ILandroid_view_MotionEvent_Handler")]
        protected override unsafe void HandleInProgressEvent (int p0, global::Android.Views.MotionEvent p1)
        {
            if (id_handleInProgressEvent_ILandroid_view_MotionEvent_ == IntPtr.Zero)
                id_handleInProgressEvent_ILandroid_view_MotionEvent_ = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "handleInProgressEvent", "(ILandroid/view/MotionEvent;)V");
            try {
                JValue* __args = stackalloc JValue [2];
                __args [0] = new JValue (p0);
                __args [1] = new JValue (p1);

                if (GetType () == ThresholdType)
                    JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod  (Handle, id_handleInProgressEvent_ILandroid_view_MotionEvent_, __args);
                else
                    JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod  (Handle, ThresholdClass, JNIEnv.GetMethodID (ThresholdClass, "handleInProgressEvent", "(ILandroid/view/MotionEvent;)V"), __args);
            } finally {
            }
        }
```

===============

I try to implement that function, but I get another error

> Error 1   Type 'Com.Almeros.Android.Multitouch.RotateGestureDetector'
>   already defines a member called 'HandleInProgressEvent' with the same
>   parameter types

```
public partial class RotateGestureDetector : global::Com.Almeros.Android.Multitouch.TwoFingerGestureDetector
    {
        protected override void HandleInProgressEvent(int p0, MotionEvent p1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's easier for us to replicate this issue if you put the actual code instead of screenshots.

Comment: @SalmonKiller: It is so long, how can I post it? Which file do you want? I can upload it and send you a link. 

Thank you.

Comment: Copy and paste is a tool you can use. Try surrounding the code with three backticks on each side for better formatting as well.